# Simulate Step down chopper circuit using any Electrical Engineering software

Tags: circuit-design, ltspice, matlab, multisim, step-down

[image: Question]

Here's my attempt:
[image: USing LTSpice (V2 = 15 , V3 (which is connected to R1) =15 V]

Could someone tell me where is my mistake ? Or simulate answer the question using any other software,please ?

Answer (score 1):

The modulation index refers to that sawtooth waveform you have as an input, which is meant to be compared with a 741 (no comment), giving you a PWM output. Thus, your source is not an FM modulated sine, but a sawtooth, with `PULSE()`. I'll let you calculate your values, but I'll hint about the rise time that can be equal to the period, while fall time and period can be zero.

I can't quite tell if the source needs to be repeating, or not, but even if it's not, `PULSE()` or `PWL()` work just fine.

Since the request behind the scenes is to see if you're able to give proper waveforms, then you can choose some models from the internal library (`2N5550` is as good as any). Don't forget to set the voltage to the value in the picture.

As a side comment, you can also eliminate `R1`, `R2`, and the two voltage sources connected to them, and keep only one source with the proper level that needs to be either `.step`ped, or dynamically adjusted (`PULSE()`, or `PWL()`, or...).